# INPUT or PREROUTING, which is first checked?

Tags: iptables

About *iptables*. I saw contradictory explanations.

[This site](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/traversingoftables.html) and most article say PREROUTING chain is checked before INPUT chain. But [another tutorial](http://www.tony-hill.info/app/download/1367500/IPTABLES+Tutorial+V1-3.pdf)(page 4-6) says INPUT is before PREROUTING. Whom to trust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The official netfilter doc](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html) states that the PREROUTING is checked before the INPUT chain. The following diagram is taken directly from the doc:

```
--->PRE------>[ROUTE]--->FWD---------->POST------>
    Conntrack    |       Mangle   ^    Mangle
    Mangle       |       Filter   |    NAT (Src)
    NAT (Dst)    |                |    Conntrack
    (QDisc)      |             [ROUTE]
                 v                |
                 IN Filter       OUT Conntrack
                 |  Conntrack     ^  Mangle
                 |  Mangle        |  NAT (Dst)
                 v                |  Filter
```